# How to plot inside while-loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

Inside a while loop, I have some function that creates all the neccesary y-values for the plot I want to make. After all the y-values are done I want my program to plot the dat(while still inside the loop), but the plot can't be made because the data won't come out until the end of the loop.
Is there anyway to do this?

Basically my code is(and I'm just going to for the first case here)

```
while c~=3
    c=menu('a','b','c')
    switch c
          case 1
             for 
                %function that creates y-values
             end
          plot(x,y)
     end
end
```

As I said; I get out all the data at the end of the loop, which is stored in the workspace. Meaning that when I run it a second time, it works fine. 
But I want to know how to make it work the first time.

Comment: Well, it completely stopped plotting altogheter, but started plotting on the first try after I reset matlab. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: `hold on` and `drawnow` are your friends

Answer (score 0):

- for Continuous line plot you can use `drawnow` and [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/338583?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) it is explained how to do this (remember to use `pause(.)` if you want to visualize the changes "real-time".
- for retain current plot when adding new plots use `hold on` as it is explained [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html)
- if you want to open different windows for every different plot you can use something like:

  `ii=1;
  while ...
     ...
     figure(ii)
     plot(x,y)
     ii=ii+1;
     ...
  end`

but be careful with the last one: if you have a big number of plots you can have some problem